# How to send sms frequently like these(daily, weekly, every 5 minutes, every hour)

Tags: java, android, sms, alarmmanager

I want to send `sms` frequently like that in question; I am using `spinner` option with some option like that`(daily,weekly,every 5 minutes)`,while i select any option in these `spinner` it has to go like that.

Alaramsms.java:

```
 private String[] Time_CATEGORY = { "Once","Every hour","Every day", "Weekdays(Mon-Fri)", "Weekend", "Every month", 
                "Every year" };

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
    edittextSmsNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smsnumber);
        edittextSmsText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smstext);
           ImageButton get = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.getc);
           spinnerTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerstate);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Time_CATEGORY);
            adapter_state
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

           Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
           Button buttonCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);


           spinnerTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            spinnerTime.setSelection(position);
            //spinnerCapital.setSelection(position);

            String myPrayer = (String) spinnerTime.getSelectedItem();


        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }});




           get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Intent i = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, ContactActivity.class);
              startActivityForResult(i, ResultCode);
          }

       });

           buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
        smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();

        picker = new Dialog(AndroidAlarmSMS.this);
        picker.setContentView(R.layout.picker_frag);
        picker.setTitle("Select Date and Time");

        datep = (DatePicker)picker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        timep = (TimePicker)picker.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        set = (Button)picker.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);



        set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(smsNumber))
                {

                        finish();
                }

                else
                {
                    String[] s =edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString().split(";");          


                for(int i=0 ;i<s.length;i++)
                {
                picker.dismiss();



        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, MyAlarmService.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", smsNumber);
                 bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", smsText);
                 myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(), datep.getDayOfMonth(), 
                timep.getCurrentHour(), timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
       // long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();        

             //   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                // calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
               // calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
                 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                 Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                   "Start Alarm with \n" +
                   "smsNumber = " + smsNumber + "\n" +
                   "smsText = " + smsText,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }

            }
        });

                picker.show();


       }});

           buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, "Cancel!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }});
       }

       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

              if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

                 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                     sendlist  =data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                     if(sendlist!=null)
                        {
                        for(int i=0;i<sendlist.size();i++)
                        {
                            edittextSmsNumber.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                            edittextSmsNumber.append(";");
                        }

                 }
                 if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    

                 }
              }
            }
        }
```

Now I am sending `sms` using scheduling time; it is going now at what user select the time.But i want to send `sms` According to `spinner` selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your AndroidAlarmSMS.Java file.

```
    private String[] Time_CATEGORY = { "Once", "Every 5 Minutes", "Every hour",
            "Every day", "Weekly", "Weekdays(Mon-Fri)", "Weekend",
            "Every month", "Every year" };

    EditText edittextSmsNumber, edittextSmsText;
    String smsNumber, smsText;
    Dialog picker;
    Button select;
    Button set;
    String mytime;
    ImageButton get;
    TimePicker timep;
    DatePicker datep;
    Integer hour, minute, month, day, year, week;
    TextView time, date;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    static int ResultCode = 12;
    ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Spinner spinnerTime;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edittextSmsNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsnumber);
        edittextSmsText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smstext);
        ImageButton get = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getc);

        datep = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        timep = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startalarm);
        Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);
        spinnerTime = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerstate);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Time_CATEGORY);
        adapter_state
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTime.setAdapter(adapter_state);

        spinnerTime.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                spinnerTime.setSelection(position);
                // spinnerCapital.setSelection(position);

                mytime = (String) spinnerTime.getSelectedItem();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                        ContactActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, ResultCode);
            }

        });

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                smsNumber = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString();
                smsText = edittextSmsText.getText().toString();

                // picker = new Dialog(AndroidAlarmSMS.this);
                // picker.setContentView(R.layout.picker_frag);
                // picker.setTitle("Select Date and Time");

                // set = (Button)picker.findViewById(R.id.btnSet);

                // set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                // @Override
                // public void onClick(View view) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(smsNumber)) {

                    finish();
                }

                else {
                    String[] s = edittextSmsNumber.getText().toString()
                            .split(";");

                    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                        // picker.dismiss();

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                                MyAlarmService.class);

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", smsNumber);
                        bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", smsText);
                        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                        // long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                        // Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        // calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        // calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
                        if (mytime.equals("Once")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);

                            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                        } else if (mytime.equals("Every 5 Minutes")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5,
                                    pendingIntent); // Millisec * Second *
                                                    // Minute
                        } else if (mytime.equals("Every hour")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60,
                                    pendingIntent); // Millisec * Second *
                                                    // Minute
                        } else if (mytime.equals("Every day")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                    24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

                        } else if (mytime.equals("Weekly")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60
                                            * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

                        } else if (mytime.equals("Weekdays(Mon-Fri)")) {

                            forWeekdays();

                        } else if (mytime.equals("Weekend")) {
                            forWeekend();

                        } else if (mytime.equals("Every month")) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 24 * 60
                                            * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

                        } else {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                            calendar.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(),
                                    datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                                    timep.getCurrentHour(),
                                    timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 365 * 24 * 60
                                            * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);

                        }

                        Toast.makeText(
                                AndroidAlarmSMS.this,
                                "Start Alarm with \n" + "smsNumber = "
                                        + smsNumber + "\n" + "smsText = "
                                        + smsText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            }

        });

        // picker.show();

        // }});

        buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, "Cancel!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    public void forWeekdays() {
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(), datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                timep.getCurrentHour(), timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);       
        int day = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);      
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5 || day == 6) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                    pendingIntent);
        }

    }

    public void forWeekend() {
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.set(datep.getYear(), datep.getMonth(), datep.getDayOfMonth(),
                timep.getCurrentHour(), timep.getCurrentMinute(), 0);       
        int day = calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (day == 1 || day == 7) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                    pendingIntent);
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                sendlist = data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                if (sendlist != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sendlist.size(); i++) {
                        edittextSmsNumber.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                        edittextSmsNumber.append(";");
                    }

                }
                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setInexactRepeating` method

For example, to set alarm "Every Day" :

```
 alarmMgr0 .setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `alarmManager.set()`, you can use `alarmManager.setRepeating()` to repeat the task..

Comment: dude according to selection,how i can use the alarm manager ,dont need repeat at all time,for once it has to send at select timeonce only,for daily ,every 5 minutes,weekly how to write that oen

Comment: @KarthickM oh.. so you want to send the sms, then prompt the user to select the next time the sms is sent???

Comment: yes,if user set daily means it has to go daily at the time picker time.like my condition,how to do that alaram manager

Comment: so it has to be repeating, if you want to send it daily basis, every 5 minutes, not only onece

Comment: @KarthickM i didnt get the TimePicker part.. What I understood was if the user is selecting the message is to be sent Daily, then the app should prompt the user daily to pick a time using TimePicker and then after this picked time is elapsed, the sms should be sent??? is that so??

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r i am having edit text of number,edit text of message,and the spinner and set alaram;in that set alaram it will picks date and time has to send,now what i want is if the user selects daily at spinner and select time at mrng 6 o clock it has to go daily 6 o clock sms,thats all

Comment: oh.. then definitely you'll have to use `setRepeating()` for that

Comment: @d3m0li5h3r for every 5 minutes,every month,evey year,weekdays for that one how to write

Answer (score 1):

You have to use setRepeating() mmethod of AlarmManager to have this achieved.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), repeat_interval, pendingIntent);
```

In the above piece of code you've to replace the value of 'repeat_interval' as per your selection i.e., daily,weekly,every 5 minutes. It denotes the interval at which the alarm repeats. But you've to pass those values in milliseconds.

Comment: i am having edit text of number,edit text of message,and the spinner and set alaram;in that set alaram it will picks date and time has to send,now what i want is if the user selects daily at spinner and select time at mrng 6 o clock it has to go daily 6 o clock sms,thats all

Comment: Then add onItemSelectedListener to the spinner and pass the selected value, so that every time you change the time it'll make the alarmManager to start.

Comment: for every 5 minutes,every month,evey year,weekdays for that one how to write

Comment: Pass the repeat_interval as,
60000 * 5 for 5 minutes,
alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30 for one month,
alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7 for one week,
alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY for every day,
alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*365 for one year.

Comment: for this intervals how to write Weekend(sat &sund),weekdays(Mon to Fri).How to write for this condition

Comment: Use Calendar.DAY_Of_WEEK which returns the day of the week as string. Just create a logic using the returned string value.

Comment: jacksson,how to do that two condition i am not getting,can you see here http://pastie.org/8516550 for remaining

Comment: I've tried and edited your code, please check it here http://pastie.org/8516774 I hope it will work.

Comment: Jacksong String day = Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

Comment: dude its not working perfectly while clicking the set itself is sending,here is my full code http://pastie.org/8516842

Comment: Its because you've set the alarm trigger time at current time, also may be you've selected weekdays. That's why it started at the current moment. Try setting a constant time to alarm.

Comment: i am not getting you correctly,what to do now,what i want to change,can you post in pastie.org what i need to change

Comment: any idea dude,while clicking the set itself the message is sending,is not sending according to our selection,its sending only once